# Call Simple Method from Java File (Fragment) in BaseAdapter : Android

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, baseadapter

I want to call `Method` which lies in `Java` File (`Fragment`) in `BaseAdapter`. I tried it by making object of `Java` File and called `Method` but it gives `nullPointerException`.
**My Sample Code :**

```
public class Test extends Fragment {
    // CustomAdapter used here...
    public void GetData() {
        // Needed coding.
    }
}

public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    getView() {
        onClickListener Event of Button (Part of each ListView Item){
            // Call GetData() method here...
         }
    }
}
```

Please help me to perform this.

Answer (score 0):

If i am not wrong all you need to do is in your CustomAdapter file,

```
`Test a;`
```

and in your OnClickListener

```
`a.GetData();`
```